# How to put gradient color in a vegabrite area chart

Tags: r, vegabrite

I am trying to mimic a Vega-lite Area chart with gradient color, using [vegabrite package](https://vegawidget.github.io/vegabrite/index.html) in R.

[image]

The above image from [Vega-lite examples](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/area_gradient.html) shows beautiful color gradient: from white (bottom) to dark-green (top).

My failed attempt (below) shows just usual green fill - what should i do to put gradient similar to the image above?

```
library(vegabrite)

vl_chart(data = 'https://vega.github.io/vega-editor/app/data/stocks.csv', 
         width = 300, height = 300) %>%
  vl_filter("datum.symbol == 'GOOG'") %>%
  vl_mark_area(stroke = "darkgreen", 
               strokeWidth = 2,
               fill = 'lightgreen', opacity = 0.4
               ) %>%
  vl_encode_x(field = 'date', timeUnit = 'yearmonth') %>%
  vl_axis_x(format = '%Y') %>% 
  vl_encode_y(field = 'price', type = 'quantitative')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my tentative solution - to use nested lists.

It required further attempts until the output JSON file becomes identical with the one shown on the Vega-lite example showcase.

```
library(vegabrite)

vl_chart(data = 'https://vega.github.io/vega-editor/app/data/stocks.csv', 
         width = 300, height = 300) %>%
  vl_filter("datum.symbol == 'GOOG'") |>
  vl_mark_area(line = list(color = "darkgreen", size = 3),
               color = list(x1 = 1,
                            x2 = 1,
                            y1 = 1,
                            y2 = 0,
                            gradient = "linear",
                            stops = list(
                              list(offset = 0, color = "white"),
                              list(offset = 1, color = "darkgreen")
                            )
               )
  ) %>%
  vl_encode_x(field = 'date', timeUnit = 'yearmonth') %>%
  vl_axis_x(format = '%Y') %>% 
  vl_encode_y(field = 'price', type = 'quantitative')
```

[image]